# Branch office printers listed in directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, printing

About a month ago we added a branch office site to our corporate domain via site-to-site VPN. A domain controller was set up at the remote site to manage logons and printers for about 10-12 employees. The new DC was linked back to the main office using AD Sites and Services, and seems to be communicating with the other domain controllers. However, when printers were being added to the desktops in the new branch office, the directory listing would show ALL the printers, including the corporate office. The same is true for desktops at the corporate office showing all branch office printers in the directory. This is a minor annoyance, but we would like to filter out branch office printers from the directory listing when adding a printer. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is a minor annoyance, but we would like to filter out branch
>   office printers from the directory listing when adding a printer.

Are you willing to live with them not being listed at all when adding a new printer (including branch users adding a new printer)?

If so, then you can choose to remove them from the "directory" in Active Directory.  You can use the Print Management console to do this.  See here: [List or Remove Printers from Active Directory Domain Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771349.aspx)

If you still want them to show up but only for users in the branch office, then you are talking something more complex using location services.  An example Technet article on this subject can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780327%28v=ws.10%29.aspx but is much more complex to setup and administer.

Comment: Implementing location services isn't really an option at this point. I guess I'll just live with it.